# How to resolve this equation $\exp(\frac{-tI}{RC}) = \cos(\omega tI)$

Tags: calculus

Is this possible to resolve this equation. I m interested in expressing $tI$ in function of $R,$ $C,$ and $w.$ Here is the equation :

$$\exp \left(\frac{-tI}{RC}\right) = \cos(\omega tI)$$ where $tI$ is between $3T/4$ and $T.$

Thank you very much !

Comment: Please elaborate what younwant

Comment: I m trying to understand at which time the two functions are equal. The two functions are equal at the time _tI_

Comment: I will place a bounty on it, nice question.

Comment: Thank you very much !

Comment: I see you have 75+ reputation, so you can practically place your own bounty

Comment: I saw you as a new user but you have a account on electrical Stack exchange, so you are freely given 100 rep!

Comment: I don't know how to it ... I m actually working on electronic.

Comment: I was just wondering where you got this equation from.........The left hand side seems similar to discharging equation of capacitor......?

Comment: You re right ! The left hand side is a discharging equation of a capacitor where R is the load. The right hand side is a sinusoidal/cosinusoidal voltage input waveform. The equation allow to know what is the ripple voltage Vpeak(1-cos(wtI) of the rectified input signal. (half brige rectifier) in function of the capacitor that you select and the load of your circuit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wish to express *tI* in terms of R, C and $\omega$ :
I suggest the follwing

$$exp(\frac{-tI}{RC})= cos(\omega tI)$$

Differenciate both sides with respect to (*tI*) ; You'll get :

$$-\frac{1}{RC}exp(\frac{-tI}{RC})= -\omega sin(\omega tI)$$

Now replace $exp(\frac{-tI}{RC})$ from previous equation,

$$-\frac{1}{RC} cos(\omega tI)=-\omega sin(\omega tI)$$

$$tan(\omega tI)=\frac{1}{RC\omega}$$

$$tI=\frac{1}{\omega} tan^{-1}(\frac{1}{RC\omega}) $$

Hope this helps....... :-)

Comment: Really nice move !

Comment: This answer is totally incorrect. You cannot just obtain the roots of an equation by differentiating both the sides and then claim that those asre the roots of the original equation as well. Simple counterexample: $x^5−x−1=0$. See Michael Hardy's answer.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\exp \left(\frac{-tI}{RC}\right) = \cos\left( \omega tI \right)
$$
$$
2 \exp \left(\frac{-tI}{RC}\right) = \exp\left( j\omega tI \right) + \exp\left( -j\omega tI \right)
$$
$$\text{where } j= \sqrt{-1}.$$
\begin{align}
& \exp\left( \frac{-tI}{RC} \right) = \exp\left( j\omega t \cdot\frac{-tI/(RC)}{j\omega t} \right) \\[8pt]
= {} & \big(\exp(j\omega t)\big)^{-I/(RCj\omega)} \\[8pt]
= {} & \big(\exp(j\omega t)\big)^{jI/(RC\omega)} \quad \text{since $1/j= -j$} \\[8pt]
= {} & a^{jI/(RC\omega)} \quad \text{where this line defines what $a$ is.}
\end{align}
So we have
$$
2a^{jI/(RC\omega)} = a + \frac 1 a.
$$
$$
2a^{1+ jI/(RC\omega)} = a^2 + 1.
$$
To solve this for $a,$ I might begin by trying Newton's method.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. So there is no way to resolve this equation without using an iterative method ? This is because it is a non linear equation ? (I m sorry I m newbie in mathematics)

Comment: I could directly apply the Newton's method on the initial equation without doing what you do ?

Comment: @Jess : It may be that for some special values of the exponent $1+jI/(RC\omega)$ it can be done without iterative methods. Certainly if that exponent is $4$ then the whole thing reduces to a quadratic equation. What if the exponent is $5$? Then it's a $5$th-degree algebraic equation. Some special cases of those can be solve by radicals; for some that can't there may be other closed forms. But in general, I will be surprised if there's a closed form.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation :)